# проблема в django. Проблема с кодировкой в uri

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, unicode

после деплоя Django проекта на хостинг. Слетает кодировка в киррилических url
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXSqI.png)
во время get запроса не находит запись
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtG0C.png)
На локальной машине все было нормально. На хостинге такая беда

Не находит данные в бд. Из-за кода на киррилице